# Cannot access a disposed object. with SignalR and Timer Manager

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-3.1, aspnetboilerplate

I wanna make my function send data as a real time (every 2 seconds or once there is change in the database table ) but the problem is there is Exception keep appread in my below code.

The exception details are:

```
'Cannot access a disposed object.
```

```
 public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IRepository<MyTable, long> _repository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;
        public HCHub(IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager,IRepository<MyTable, long> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;

        }

        

        public  void Get(TestDto testDto)
        {
            try {
                using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
                {
                    var result=  _repository.GetDbContext().Set<MyTable>()
               .Include(x => x.list)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.list2)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.obj).ToList();




                    new TimerManager(async () =>

                    await Clients.All.SendAsync("listen", result) //<====== in this Line the exception occured
                    
                    
                    );
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
            }



        }
```

and TimerManager Code is

```
public class TimerManager
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent;
        private Action _action;

        public DateTime TimerStarted { get; }

        public TimerManager(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
            _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            _timer = new Timer(Execute, _autoResetEvent, 1000, 2000);
            TimerStarted = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void Execute(object stateInfo)
        {
            _action();

            if ((DateTime.Now - TimerStarted).Seconds > 60)
            {
                _timer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

So the problem is in **Timer Manager** or in **myHub** or the way that I'm simulate the realtime data by **TimerManager** is not acceptable ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you exit the hub method you aren't guaranteed to be able to access the `Clients` property. If you want to do something like that, you should inject an `IHubContext<THub>` into your Hubs constructor and use that instead. You can read more about `IHubContext` in https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1#get-an-instance-of-ihubcontext